# I see "Command 'alis' not found" every time I open a terminal

Tags: command-line

Every time I open a new terminal window, I see this message:

```
Command 'alis' not found, did you mean:

  command 'als' from deb atool (0.39.0-10)
  command 'ali' from deb mailutils-mh (1:3.7-2.1)
  command 'ali' from deb mmh (0.4-2)
  command 'ali' from deb nmh (1.7.1-6)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: You probably have a mis-spelled `alias` in your `~/.bashrc` file (or related shell initialization file). Open it with a text editor and take a look.

Comment: Thank you solved by editing and correcting the spelling